# Read csv in pandas with different separator (commas)

Tags: pandas, csv

I want to read a CSV file and save it as data frame in pandas.

But I have a problem because I have rows like this:

```
BG,6141.6,6141.6,,3.0,,,ic
```

As you see there are three separators: `',,,'` , `',,'` and `,`

How can I load it correctly into pandas?

Comment: You should take a close look at data, most likely the multiple separators would mean that your data has 8 columns but columns 4,6 and 7 in this particular row are blank

Comment: Is that because the columns are empty or some other reason?

Comment: You should indicate what you already tried, and why you consider it did not work.

Comment: What is header of `csv`? Are there column names?

Comment: @jezrael yes, there are. The problem is, that instead of 1 million rows pandas reads only 45000. I didn't use some special options, only provided the path. The structure of data I gave in the post. What the solution could be?

Comment: @A-Za-z maybe you are right. But somehow pandas reads only 45000 rows instead of 1 million...

Comment: @yef_dan_92 - how do you verify number of rows? do you try some editor like notepad++ if use win? Without data it is really hard. :(

Comment: @yef_dan_92, you can print df.columns  on the dataframe with 45000 rows that got created and see how many columns are there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex separator `[,]+` - one or more `,`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""iBG,6141.6,6141.6,,3.0,,,ic"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep="[,]+", header=None, engine='python')
print (df)
     0       1       2    3   4
0  iBG  6141.6  6141.6  3.0  ic
```